# How can I clear portion of what is typed into the prompt while working on Linux and using C-shell?

Tags: command-line, csh, line-editor

I am working in Linux and C-shell. Often times I would require to change some portion of what is there already in the prompt that I obtain from reverse searching through the history command by use of <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd>. I do not want to use the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for doing this. I have looked at [this question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/324601/how-do-i-clear-what-i-typed-into-the-prompt) which was specifically for bash.
This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/324638/173338) says to use <kbd>CTRL+U</kbd> which would clear out everything before the current cursor position. But this is clearing out everything for me even though I have hit a few backspaces and now am at the middle of the text in the prompt. Is there a C-shell specific way of achieving the same in Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `tcsh` (which I suppose is what you're calling "C-Shell" if you're not totally masochist) in `emacs` mode (usually the default), you can use <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>. That's the `kill-region` widget which deletes between the *mark* (set with <kbd>Ctrl-Space</kbd> but defaults to the beginning of the line) and the cursor.

In that regard, its behaviour is closer to emacs' than with bash(readline)/ksh/zsh emacs mode, but departs from the terminal driver embedded line editor (in canonical mode), where <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> deletes the previous word (`werase`, also in `vi`). That time it chose `emacs` over usual terminal behaviour but not in the case of <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> where in emacs it's the universal argument while it's the `kill`-line character in the terminal.

If you'd rather <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> delete to the beginning of the line, you can also do:

```
bindkey '^U' backward-kill-line
```

En `vi` mode, <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go to command mode, and <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to delete to the beginning of the line (or <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> if you want to change instead of deleting that).

Comment: You said "In that regard, its behaviour is closer to emacs' than with bash(readline)/ksh/zsh emacs mode, but departs from the terminal driver embedded line editor (in canonical mode)". Can you please explain what you meant by *emacs'* and *bash(readline)/ksh/zsh emacs mode* and terminal driver embedded line editor(in canonical mode)?