# What is meant by a shell is in "vi" mode or "emacs" mode?

Tags: shell, command-line, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi-mode

This question follows directly from [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85106/28032). In this case I am specifically unable to understand the part which says:

> In that regard, its behaviour is closer to emacs' than with
>   bash(readline)/ksh/zsh emacs mode, but departs from the terminal
>   driver embedded line editor (in canonical mode), where <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> deletes
>   the previous word (werase, also in vi).

Here we are talking about shells and not editors which are two completely different programs. What does it mean to say shell is in some editor mode?

P.S: You can base your answer on the premise that I understand what a shell is and how to use vim for basic editing.

Comment: This is not about core shell functionality per se, but rather about line editing (what you do when you make a typo and go back and correct yourself).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In "vi" mode you can edit/navigate on the current shell prompt like a line in the vi editor. You can look at it like a one-line text file. Analogously in "emacs" mode you can edit/navigate the current command line using (some) of Emacs' shortcuts.

### Example

For example in vi-mode you can do something like (in bash):

```
$ set -o vi
$ ls hello world
<ESC>
bbdw # results in
$ ls world
```

In emacs-mode you can hit e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to jump at the start of a line (vi: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>). You can turn on emacs mode via `set -o emacs` (in bash, ksh, zsh etc.).

### Readline

A lot of interactive command line programs (including [bash](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)) use the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library. Thus, you can configure which input mode to use (vi or emacs) and other options in one place such that every program using readline has the exact same editing/navigating interface.

For example my readline configuration looks like:

```
$ cat ~/.inputrc 
set editing-mode vi
set blink-matching-paren on
```

For example [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh.html#Top)/[ksh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korn_shell) does not use readline as far as I know, but also support vi/emacs modes that are very much like the bash/readline one.

Of course, the vi/emacs mode in a command line shell is just a subset of the complete editor feature set. Not every feature makes sense in a command line shell, and some features are more complicated to support than others.

### Canonical Mode

Before vi/emacs modes of interactive command line shells 'were invented' your shell would use just the [canonical mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Canonical_mode_processing) of your terminal which only provides a limited set of editing commands (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to delete the last word.

Comment: Suppose I don't know on which Input mode I am on. Can I verify it by entering some text and press [Ctrl] + [A]?
if cursor moves to beginning its emacs else it vi?

Comment: @limovala, should be a good approximation. Depends on your shell of course - if CTL+A does not work another possibility is that your shell does not include any editing mode. Perhaps some shells also implement other editing modes. But in practice your method should be good enough. You can also test with a vi command after that to be more sure. In bash you can also use something like `set -o | grep 'emacs\|vi'`. In zsh (where I have vi-mode) this does not work, though.

Comment: bind -P will also give good indication of which mode one is in

Answer (score 27):

You'll notice that when you run `cat` at a shell prompt on a terminal, `cat` being supposed to write to stdout what it reads from stdin, and press <kbd>a</kbd>, you see a `a` echoed back by the terminal driver, but `cat` doesn't write that `a` (you see only one `a`, the one echoed by the terminal driver).

However, if you type <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you don't see `cat` outputting `a\010b\015`, but `b\012` (`b` and newline).

That is because the terminal driver (we're talking software in the kernel, not in the terminal emulator like `xterm`) implements a very basic *line editor* when in *canonical* mode. The terminal driver can be configured using `ioctl()` system calls like when using the `stty` command. For instance, to leave the canonical mode, you can do `stty -icanon`. If you do:

```
stty -icanon; cat
```

Then, you'll see both the `echo` (which you could have disabled with `stty -echo`) and the `cat` output at the same time.

That editor is a line editor. That is, it is for the user to edit one line of text until it's sent to the application reading the terminal device upon pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The editing capabilities of that *editor* are very limited. In most implementations, there are only 4 editing keys (actually characters) also configurable with `stty`:

- erase (`^H` or `^?` usually): erase the previous character
- kill (`^U` usually): empty (kill) the line entered so far
- werase (`^W`): erase the previous word
- lnext (`^V`): enter the next character literally (cancel the special meaning of all of the above)

Back in the old days, it was thought that that terminal driver line editor would be extended with fancier capabilities. That is why none of the early shells has any command line editing capabilities (you'd get the same line editing capabilities at the shell prompt than when running `cat` like we did above).

However, that really never happened, maybe part of the reason being the mess with different terminals not sending the same characters upon some key presses which made it evident that that should not be implemented in kernel space.

So some shells started dropping the *canonical* mode of the terminal driver and implementing their own line editor. At the time, `emacs` and `vi` were the most popular visual text editors with completely different key binding and operation mode. In `vi`, you have one mode for entering text, and one for editing. In `emacs`, you're always in *entering text* mode, but editing is done by pressing key combinations (like `^b` to move the character backward).

There was no point for shells at the time to come up with their own different key binding. That would have caused frustration for people to have to learn a different one. However, choosing one (`emacs` or `vi`) style over the other would have been a sure way to alienate the users of the *other* editor.

According to https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/vhll/full_papers/korn.ksh.a:

> The popular inline editing features (vi and emacs  mode)  of ksh   were
>   created   by   software   developers   at  Bell Laboratories; the vi line
>   editing mode by Pat Sullivan,  and the  emacs  line  editing  mode  by  Mike
>   Veach.   Each had independently  modified  the  Bourne  shell  to  add   these
>   features,  and both were in organizations that wanted to use ksh  only  if  ksh
>   had  their  respective  inline   editor. Originally  the  idea  of adding
>   command line editing to ksh was rejected in the hope that line editing would
>   move  into the  terminal  driver.   However,  when it became clear that this
>   was not likely to happen soon, both line editing  modes were  integrated  into
>   ksh  and  made optional so that they could be disabled on systems that provided
>   editing  as  part of the terminal interface.

So instead, they implemented both and an interface for users to choose between the two. `ksh` was most probably the first in the early 80s (reusing code that had been written separately to add a vi mode and an emacs mode to the Bourne shell as seen above) followed by `tcsh` (`tcsh` initially only had `emacs` key binding, `vi` mode was added later) and later `bash` and `zsh` in the early 90s.

You switch between the two modes in `bash`, `zsh` or `ksh` with `set -o vi` or `set -o emacs`, and with `bindkey -e` or `bindkey -v` in `tcsh` or `zsh`.

POSIX actually specifies the `vi` mode and not the `emacs` mode for `sh` (the story has that [Richard Stallman objected to POSIX specifying the `emacs` mode for `sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_18)).

The default mode for `bash`, the public domain variants of `ksh` (pdksh, mksh, oksh), `tcsh` and `zsh` is the emacs mode (though with `zsh`, it's `vi` if your `$EDITOR` is `vi`), while in the AT&T `ksh`, it's the *dumb* mode unless `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` mentions `vi` or `emacs`.

`ksh` also later added a `gmacs` mode to accommodate users of Gosling `emacs` that handled <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> differently.

Now the handling of `^W` in `emacs` or in `tcsh` emacs mode probably predates the `werase` character in the terminal line editor, so we can't really blame them for that and my statement about *"departing..."* may be seen as misleading. It's just that I find it irritating when things like `emacs`, `tcsh` or `info` behave differently from everything else when you type <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>. You can imagine I found it a lot more irritating when some applications started to close their window when you typed  <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd>.

Comment: `pdksh` also parses `$EDITOR` for `vi` and switches modes upon startup; I removed that for `mksh` (especially as I only really maintain the Emacs mode anyway).

Comment: Thank you so much addition, especially with the detailed discussion of the behavior and history of various shells. As someone who is regularly required to work in different distros with shells I didn't configure, this is extraordinarily helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent historical context. It's a pity that more sophisticated inline editing features weren't added to the terminal driver at that time. There'd be no need for programs to include libraries such as Readline. I had also wondered why Emacs-mode isn't specified by POSIX so that link to the Rationale was interesting. (I also share your frustration with `^W` closing windows).

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan, we'd still need things like zle/readline as things like filename/command completion could not really be done in the terminal driver.