# How to enable bash auto-completion in SunOS?

Tags: bash, solaris

In SunOS 5.10, I could not get bash autocompletion (when TAB is pressed) to work. Arrow keys do not go through history either. Also, even though `PS1` is set to `\u@\h:\w\$`, on command prompt it shows `u@h:w$`. Any ideas how can I fix it?

This is the result of `pkginfo -l SUNWbash` command:

```
   PKGINST:  SUNWbash
   NAME:  GNU Bourne-Again shell (bash)
   CATEGORY:  system
   ARCH:  i386
   VERSION:  11.10.0,REV=2005.01.08.01.09
   BASEDIR:  /
   VENDOR:  Sun Microsystems, Inc.
   DESC:  GNU Bourne-Again shell (bash) version 3.0
   PSTAMP:  sfw10-patch-x20070430084427
   INSTDATE:  Aug 28 2012 15:01
   HOTLINE:  Please contact your local service provider
   STATUS:  completely installed
   FILES:        3 installed pathnames
               2 shared pathnames
               2 directories
               1 executables
            1194 blocks used (approx)
```

BTW I am connecting through `ssh` from Max OSX.

And I can't even learn the version of bash:`bash --version` command creates a subshell.

Comment: The default shell the plain old Bourne Shell, not Bourne Again Shell ie. bash, I think. See [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/customize-89075/index.html) about Solaris shells.

Comment: The default shell is actually bash: `echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/bash`.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` ?

Comment: Can you run `shopt|grep compat` just to make sure you're really running bash? It should output at least one compat line.

Answer (score 3):

In Solaris 10 plain-old Bourne Shell was still the default shell, not Bash. This changed in 2011 with the release of Solaris 11.

For Solaris 10 and supposing your user is 'john', then do as follows.

1. Change to root: `su - root`
2. Execute : `usermod -s /usr/bin/bash john`.

You'll need to logout from 'john' completely and login again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have root access. I tried to run `/usr/bin/bash`, but it is still the same. It looks like `tcsh` has some kind of auto-completition.

Answer (score 0):

To restore autocompletion and history navigation with arrow keys (without changing your interactive shell like peterh suggested although that is totally alright), try the following command:

```
$ set -o emacs
```

If that does not work, try :

```
$ export EDITOR=emacs
```

Copy whatever command works for you in you `~/.profile` and this should be set automatically whenever you open a terminal.

Comment: I tried it too, still does not work :(

Comment: Well, seems plain sh terminal only supports vi style in-line edition :(.
Here is some additional information: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85390/what-is-meant-by-a-shell-is-in-vi-mode-or-emacs-mode

Comment: And here is a cheat sheet to using vi style in line edition mode : http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my Solaris 10:

```
tcsh
set autolist
```

<kbd>TAB</kbd> should work from there on in your terminal.